# How can I have the word count of a selected text that contains references in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I have the word count of a selected text that contains references in Microsoft Word?

When the selected text contains references, the word count is totally off, e.g.:

[image]

I use Microsoft Word 2013 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Is the reference 18, 38, 48, to paragraphs? or links with many words?

Comment: @ejbytes references: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwFwU.png

Comment: Your image link shows 6 references. But if you include all 48 or 50 or 100 references (links to references) it might add up to the 1700 extra words. Perhaps?

Comment: @ejbytes yes I have 73 references which add up to 1805 words

Answer (score 0):

Correspondence:

> "Your image link shows 6 references. But if you include all 48 or 50
>   or 100 references (links to references) it might add up to the 1700
>   extra words. Perhaps?"

Seems that the references, or links to references, ADD to your total word count wnen selecting them.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Word 2010, but you may have a similar option in 2013 when doing your word count. I have a box to uncheck so that footnotes and endnotes are excluded.

[image: Screenshot of Word 2010 Word Count window]